# Why Iam getting this value as a NULL

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I am getting the below erro, when I provide the findOne function.  It is displaying NULL, couldn't find the solution as there are records with the title.

```
 db.links.findOne({title: "MongoDB TUtor"});
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54f3ea83663952fddd7aaa54"),
        "title" : "MongoDB TUtor",
        "url" : "mongo.com",
        "comment" : "document-oriented db"
    }
    > db.links.findOne({title: "true"});
    null
    > db.links.findOne({title: 1});
    null
```

--

Records in links collection

```
 db.links.find().forEach(printjson)

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3ea83663952fddd7aaa54"),

"title" : "MongoDB TUtor",

"url" : "mongo.com",

"comment" : "document-oriented db"

}

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3ebe7663952fddd7aaa55"),

"title" : "Mongo DB handson",

"url" : "https://university.mongo.com",

"comment" : [

"NoSQL",

"Document-based"

],

"filed_on" : ISODate("2015-03-02T04:47:02.131Z"),

"meta" : {

"browser" : [

"Google Chrome",

"MAC Safari"

],

"version" : "13.4.3.7"

}

}

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3f77e663952fddd7aaa5a"),

"title" : "MongoDB_database",

"url" : "mongo.com",

"comment" : "document-oriented db"

}

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3f7b7663952fddd7aaa5c"),

"title" : "database",

"url" : "mongo.com",

"comment" : "document-oriented db"

}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f3fa5f663952fddd7aaa5d"), "title" : "Rocky" }

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3facf663952fddd7aaa5e"),

"title" : "Arnold",

"userId" : ObjectId("54f3fa5f663952fddd7aaa5d")

}

> db.links.find().pretty()

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3ea83663952fddd7aaa54"),

"title" : "MongoDB TUtor",

"url" : "mongo.com",

"comment" : "document-oriented db"

}

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3ebe7663952fddd7aaa55"),

"title" : "Mongo DB handson",

"url" : "https://university.mongo.com",

"comment" : [

"NoSQL",

"Document-based"

],

"filed_on" : ISODate("2015-03-02T04:47:02.131Z"),

"meta" : {

"browser" : [

"Google Chrome",

"MAC Safari"

],

"version" : "13.4.3.7"

}

}

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3f77e663952fddd7aaa5a"),

"title" : "MongoDB_database",

"url" : "mongo.com",

"comment" : "document-oriented db"

}

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3f7b7663952fddd7aaa5c"),

"title" : "database",

"url" : "mongo.com",

"comment" : "document-oriented db"

}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f3fa5f663952fddd7aaa5d"), "title" : "Rocky" }

{

"_id" : ObjectId("54f3facf663952fddd7aaa5e"),

"title" : "Arnold",

"userId" : ObjectId("54f3fa5f663952fddd7aaa5d")

}
```

Comment: There is no document with a title of "true" - what were you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you do it. The way you are querying this it is looking for an actual document that either has `"title": true` or `"title": 1`. Of course, none of your documents meet that condition.

When you want to find out if that field is "actually there" then you use the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator to test for the presence:

```js
db.links.findOne({ "title": { "$exists": true } })
```

Or naturally with the reverse case when looking for documents that do not have the matching field.